# Especifying Hexadecimal values in an array in C for bitmap files

Tags: c, bitmap, vga

I have a simple question regarding how the header file of a bitmap is read.

I have my bitmap array like this:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
char bitmap[(188*180)+1024+54];  //The image size is 188*180  +  the header file of 54 bytes+ the pallete table´s 1024 bytes
```

I´m specifying the values according to the bmp header, but I have a question when having a value that´s bigger than a byte. For example, my image width is 288 which is 0x120 in hexadecimal. However I cannot simply say:

```
 bitmap[19] = 0x120;
```

because that´s bigger than one byte.  According to what I read I have a double word to store my image height (That is 4 bytes) so I can use `bitmap[20]`,`bitmap[21]` and `bitmap[22]` to store the entire number.

How should I divide the number to get the same value stored on the header file? I´m not sure if the values are added or are read as a single hex number when opening the bmp file.

Comment: Find the `struct` definition which describes the bitmap header, and watch out for endianness. You *can* split a number into its bytes, but endianness will still be an issue.

Comment: In the C standard byte is the same as `char`, so `typedef`ing it explicitly is useless and confusing at best. If you intended to have an 8 bit type (i.e. octet), note that a byte does not necessarily have 8 bits. Use `stint.h` types for fixed-width (and specific encoding). Also note that `char` has no standard signed-ness.

Comment: You'll also need to research "bits per pixel" (yours is 8), and "stride", because the bitmap row length might be greater than the image width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

The values are read as a single `DWORD` (32-bit) number.

---

BMP file format is described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format), as well as in numerous places on the Internet. Please note that the proper offset is 18, not 19 as you suggest in your question. So the four bytes are at offsets 18, 19, 20 and 21.

In your code:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
char bitmap[(188*180)+1024+54];
```

to force the width of the image to `0x120`, you can do this:

```
bitmap[18] = 0x20;
bitmap[19] = 0x01;
bitmap[20] = 0x00;
bitmap[21] = 0x00;
```

Or in the general case:

```
uint32_t width = ...; // 0x120 in your case, any value in general case
bitmap[18] = width & 0xff;
bitmap[19] = (width >> 8) & 0xff;
bitmap[20] = (width >> 16) & 0xff;
bitmap[21] = (width >> 24) & 0xff;
```

Note that the least-significant bytes should be at lower addresses (little-endian order) - this is not always documented, but is always implied when talking about data structures in Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was just what I needed!